Return the corresponding pay and revenue values based on the range of numbers that includes a lookup value
If using data similar to below, How can I have it so that a lookup number included within a number range returns the corresponding pay and revenue?
Data Example:
Miles    Revenue   Pay 
0-55     200       50
56-75    280       70
So, if 60 miles is entered in a cell, since 60 falls within 56-75, the formula will return 280 and 70.

Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?


First create a lookup table in Columns E to G with the bottom cutoff values in column E:




A - D
E
F
G




1

Miles
Revenue
Pay


2

0
200
50


3

56
280
70




In A2 put your lookup value.

In B2  and C2 use VLOOKUP to return the values:
=VLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])


Specify index 2 in B2:
=VLOOKUP(A2, $D$2:$F$3, 2, 1)


Specify index 3 in C2:
=VLOOKUP(A2, $D$2:$F$3, 3, 1)





A
B
C       
             D     
E
F
G




1
Lookup Values
Revenue
Pay

Miles
Revenue
Pay


2
60
280
70

0
200
50


3




56
280
70






To simplify you can put an array formula in B2 to calculate both columns and multiple rows.
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", VLOOKUP(A2:A, $E$2:$G$3, {2,3}, 1),))




